# CakePHP class custom import

Tags: cakephp

I have a site in cakephp 2.X and I want to load a class (less2c.php) into my controller to use it inside my model.
I have put my file lessc.php inside the folder `/app/Lib`
Into my controller I have done this:

```
App::uses('Less2c', 'Lib');
class WidgetsController extends AppController {

}
```

And into my Model Widget I have done this:

```
public function beforeSave(){
    $less = new Less2c();
    try {
     $less->compile("invalid LESS } {");
    } catch (exception $e) {
     return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But when I try to save return me:

```
Error: Class 'Less2c' not found
```

What I'm wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you App::uses() the class in the wrong file? You need to put the statement to include another class in the file where it actually is being used, in your case your Widget model. Your controller calls the model which then internally uses this Less2c class - so the controller doesnt have to know about it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i guess your  class name should be `Lessc` instead of `Less2c` so there is one error in including your external lib to load into cakephp model and controlller just try to change with

```
App::uses('Lessc', 'Lib'); instead of App::uses('Less2c', 'Lib');
```

Or if you can still not found working then please go throw this [cakephp.org](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html) Document for loading external library in cakephp 2.X

Comment: ops sorry mine error to copy the code, I have changed it but same error Error: Class 'Less2c' not found  (view the update question)

Comment: will you please go throw this link will sure help you just compare with your actual code